# Link a many2one field to a specific field of another class

Tags: python, odoo

I have a class created with the following code

```
class exp(osv.osv):
    _name = "sim.exp"
    _description = "xxx"
    _columns = {
        'building': fields.many2one('sim.buildings','Building',required=True,ondelete='cascade'),
        'owner': fields.many2one('sim.student','Name of Owner',required=True,ondelete='cascade'),
    }
exp()
```

I have a specific problem with the `owner` field which for some reason gives me back the `regnum` field and I wish to get back the `student_name` field instead

My `sim.student` class looks like the following

```
class student(osv.osv):
    _name = "sim.student"
    _description = "xxx"
    _columns = {
        'student_name': fields.char('Name',size=256,required=True),
        'regnum': fields.char('Registration Number',size=256,required=True),
        'father_name': fields.char('Last Name',size=256),
        'gender':fields.selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')],'Gender'),
        'contact_no':fields.char('e-mail',size=256),
        'building': fields.many2one('sim.buildings','Consorcio',required=True,ondelete='cascade'),

    }
student()
```

Is there any way to specifically get the `student_name` ?

Any tip in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not specify `rec_name` in you `sim.student' class.

Add `rec_name` in your class:

```
class student(osv.osv):
    rec_name = 'student_name'
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of _rec_name . I am wondering now what happens if I need to get another field from the same column, I guess _rec_name wont apply in that case. Anyway I guess if I get to that situation I post another question. Thanks for your help

Comment: In that case you can use `fields.related`